# Need to catalog a large web application

Tags: web, snapshot, catalog

We have a web application with over 560 pages.  I would like a way to catalog the site somehow so that I can review the pages (without having to find each on in the menu or enter the URL).  Be very glad for ideas on the best way to go about this.

I'd be happy to end up with 560 image files or PDFs, or one large PDF or whatever.  I can easily put together a script with all the URLs, but how to pull those up and take a snapshot of some sort and save that to a file or files is where I need help.

The site is written in Java (server) and javascript (client).

Comment: Please clarify if pages are HTML with JavaScript for styling, or fully built with JavaScript.

Comment: If the former, you will be able to use a web crawler to crawl the pages. There are several in source forge. If the latter, you may need to automate a browser using selenium. We can suggest tools once the answer is known.

Comment: http://www.openwebspider.org/

Comment: The pages are HTML with javascript for styling and automation.

Comment: I assume you have access to the source / filesystem?

Comment: Yes, I have access to the source code, and could easily cause any given page to come up with a script.

Comment: Just took a look at openwebspider.org. Only the source code is there, and it appears to be C-Sharp, source code only (no binaries).  We're a Java shop, so I don't think that will help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great plugin for Firefox that made this relatively painless.  The plugin is called Screenshot Pimp (hate the name, love what it does).  It takes a snapshot of your browser contents and immediately saves it to a file on your hard drive.

So then I wrote a script that would pull each page up in an IFrame with the URL showing above that, and took snapshots of each page.  It took a couple hours to cycle through the whole set of 560+ pages, but it worked great, and now I have a catalog of all the pages.